# Comparison of Date From SQL Server and C# DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a `DateTime` column in a SQL Server database. The data stored as follows:

```
2020-10-04 23:45:00.527
```

I tried to compare the date as follows with current date (Date in database should be less than current date)

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;

 var result = (from c in TableName
               where (c.Email == email) && 
                     c.Password == password && c.Status == 1 && 
                     c.ValidTill.Date <= today
               select c).ToList();
```

But unfortunately I get this exception

> 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Even tried the below method, that doesn't seem to work:

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.ValidTill)
```

My comparison would be like this -

```
2020-10-04 23:45:00 (Datetime in database) <= 2020-10-10 23:00:00 (current date & time)
```

Comment: You could do `var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)` and then `c.ValidTill < tomorrow` as that will make sure the date is before tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.Date`

```
    c.ValidTill <= today
```

or comparing only with date

```
    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ValidTill) <= today.Date
```

needs to do the work.

Comment: Will the comparison work as there is no formatting done?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var today = DateTime.Now;
 var result = (from c in TableName
               where (c.Email == email) && 
                     c.Password == password && c.Status == 1 && 
                     c.ValidTill <= today
               select c).ToList();

hope it will work.
```

Comment: in your case today is still of DateTime type and it will lead to the same exception.